# Keep Web App User Logged In with Google Sign-In for Web

Tags: google-signin, google-oauth

I have built a web app that is using Google federated login as the only login option (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/).  Currently, every time a user visits the web app, they are prompted to select a Google account and enter password.  If the user has previously signed into the app or is currently signed into the correct Google Account, I want to bypass the login page and direct them to the application.

Context: The goal of this sign in page is to verify the domain of the logged in user.  If the logged in user belongs to a certain domain (ex. @samplecompany.com), the user may proceed to the application.  If not, they are prompted to login with the correct Google Account.

If possible, I want to check the logged in user's domain without prompting the user to sign in.  If not, I need to find a way for the user to bypass the sign in page when they return to the web application after initially logging into the web app.

As further context, the javascript for the login page code is currently:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
<script>
var googleUser = {};
var startApp = function() {
  gapi.load('auth2', function(){
    auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
      client_id: 'clientid',
      cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
    });
    var options = new gapi.auth2.SigninOptionsBuilder();
    attachSignin(document.getElementById('button'), options, auth2);
  });
};

function attachSignin(element, options, auth2) {
  auth2.attachClickHandler(element, options,
      function(googleUser) {
            email = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
            domain = googleUser.getHostedDomain();
            if (domain == 'samplecompany.com'){
              //Proceed to application               
            }
            else {
            auth2.signOut();
            alert ('Please sign in with samplecompany.com email.'); 
          }

      }, function(error) {
        auth2.signOut();
      });
}
startApp();
</script>
```

I have searched for a way to access basic user information without walking through the OAuth process and it seems impossible.  I would really appreciate thoughts on how to avoid requiring the user to login every time they visit the app when all I need to verify is the user's domain.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you googled 'cookies`?

Comment: does it keep the login prompt even if the user checked "remember my password", or does it automatically log him in in a couple of seconds?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

Step 1: 
When user logs in with google "sign in with google" , provide a checkbox "stay logged in"

step 2: if user checks "stay logged in" when signing in with google, then set a cookie in the browser with an expiry date may be 60 days from now or something with the user's email. (check jquery cookies, it's easy: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)

step 3: Next time user opens your web app,check if the cookie is valid then just redirect them to their account page/dashboard

Overall if user chooses to stay logged in, they prevent the login process everytime they visit your web app. If they don't they have to login manually with "sign in with google".